# How to make FullCalendar load on a specified month's view?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I'd like to pass a parameter to FullCalendar when it's loading so that the first view the user sees is the month that I've specified. So far I've found this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  // options
});

var CurrentDate = new Date();
var CurrentYear = CurrentDate.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', CurrentYear, 7);
```

The code above works but the plugin is written quite well so I'm guessing there's a way to pass this information to the plugin as options initially. Could anyone point me to an example or documentation of how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick: [Full Calender docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/month/)